# Bootstrap negative margin in panel-heading not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The `.panel-heading` has padding of 15px right and left in bootstrap. I want the input field to expand 100% inside the `.panel-heading`. I tried the negative margin:

```
input.form-control {
   text-align:center;
   border: 5px solid #ccc;
   height: 40px;
   margin-left: -15px;
   margin-right: -15px;
}
```

But only the left side is working. How can I get the right side to work as well?

```css
.col-xs-12 {
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}

.panel-heading {
 position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: -moz-sticky;
   position: -ms-sticky;
   position: -o-sticky;
   position: sticky;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 99999;
 top: 0;
}

.glyphicon-arrow-left {
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.panel-heading h1 {
 padding-bottom: 0.65em;
 color: #3399ff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-body {
 padding: 0;
}

input.form-control {
   text-align:center;
   border: 5px solid #ccc;
   height: 40px;
   margin-left: -15px;
   margin-right: -15px;
}

.users {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.users li {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
 color: #000;
}

.users li .username {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.users li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

.users a {
 display: block;
 height: 45px;
 padding: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-centered'>
   <div class='panel panel-default'>
    <div class='panel-heading sticky'>
     <div class='back pull-left'><a href='chats.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left'></a></span></div>
     <h1 class='panel-title text-center'>New Chat</h1>
     <input class='form-control' id='searchUser' type='text' placeholder='Search'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
     <ul class='users'>
      <li class='user text-center'>
       <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span><strong class='username'>John Appleseed</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!--end column-->
 </div><!--end row 1-->
</div><!--end container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/enmyngeh/

```css
.col-xs-12 {
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}

.panel-heading {
 position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: -moz-sticky;
   position: -ms-sticky;
   position: -o-sticky;
   position: sticky;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 99999;
 top: 0;
}

.glyphicon-arrow-left {
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.panel-heading h1 {
 padding-bottom: 0.65em;
 color: #3399ff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-body {
 padding: 0;
}

input.form-control {
   text-align:center;
   border: 5px solid #ccc;
   height: 40px;
   margin-left: -15px;
   width: calc(100% + 30px);
   
}

.users {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.users li {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
 color: #000;
}

.users li .username {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.users li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

.users a {
 display: block;
 height: 45px;
 padding: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-centered'>
   <div class='panel panel-default'>
    <div class='panel-heading sticky'>
     <div class='back pull-left'><a href='chats.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left'></span></a></div>
     <h1 class='panel-title text-center'>New Chat</h1>
     <input class='form-control' id='searchUser' type='text' placeholder='Search'>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
     <ul class='users'>
      <li class='user text-center'>
       <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span><strong class='username'>John Appleseed</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!--end column-->
 </div><!--end row 1-->
</div><!--end container-->
```

Change of code

```
input.form-control {
   text-align:center;
   border: 5px solid #ccc;
   height: 40px;
   margin-left: -15px;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

Since you have extra `15px` `padding` on left & right of `panel-heading`, so you need to add that missing space to `input`.
`calc(100% + 30px)`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why my negative margin doesn't work?

Comment: @RobertRocha.. `margin-left` is working, but the problem lies with the parent div. Parent container was having `padding` of `15px` on **left** & **right**. So, even children width 100% will exclude padding 15px. That's why I added 30px.